# Access array outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, function

I need the results of the array outside of the function. Is there anyway to do that?

I am trying to push the results of a json object to an array to use.

```
let chan = [];
axios.get(names, {
    cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
      api_requests.nm = c;
    })
  })
  .then(function(name) {
    chan = name.data.map(d => d.elem);
    return chan;
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert_error(error);
  });
```

I want to use the results of `chan` outside of this function globally. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: You probably look for async await  , then you can be able to use the result in your async function only ,coz return from async function will wrap it into promise

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: Look at this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474073/using-axios-with-async-and-await

Comment: @Shubh, I keep getting errors, I tried what was suggested in that post. Is there a way to try and help me debug my code?

Comment: You probably ,should see the axios docs correctly ,otherwise there are other libraries like npm request which are made for this tasks and have good documentation too.